# SQL Query mishap

Tags: mysql

New SQL'er here. Okay for a school assignment I decided to build the tables in the question so I can test my queries for correctness.

One of the questions is simply show all employees that share the same office. Easy I think

```
SELECT office, name
 FROM my_db.employee
 GROUP BY office;
```

but when I run this it returns only the first tuple of each unique office not all grouped by office.

Is something wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1):

You can only select columns that are in the group by statement, or are using aggregate functions (sum, count, etc.)

So,

```
select office, count(name) from my_db.employee group by office;
```

would work, but it's not what you want of course.

You might want something as simple as

```
select office, name from my_db.employee order by office
```

which would show them 'grouped' by office.  GROUP BY requires SQL to only issue one row per GROUP BY variable[s] - which is not 'grouping' in the sense your assignment asks, I'd think.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation on proper GROUP BY querying!

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie to SQL, you will need to learn to differentiate on what is being asked...

I want all people who work for Office "X" (use a WHERE clause -- Office = 'X' that you are interested in)

I want to know HOW MANY work for each office ( use GROUP BY clause, and include all fields you are "grouping by").

Group By is associated with doing aggregates on some column(s) you want in common.  How many car sales for a dealership.  How many car sales for dealership per month... per month per model vehicle.

When doing aggregates, these are typically associated with MIN(), MAX(), SUM(), AVG(), etc, and the group by in many engines requires you to list all non-aggregate fields for grouping purposes.

The answer from Explosion Pills' is probably closest to what you want, and is an exception of an aggregate function that is not numeric or comparable (such as min(), max()).  Group_Concat() tells the engine to just build a list of strings one after the other as long as they are all in the same "group" classification (such as your Office) example.

Good luck on your education, and there are many out here who can help along.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I had a feeling I must have been using GROUP BY incorrectly. Nice to have it spelt out so clearly. Back to reading my class notes!

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the SELECT portion must appear in the GROUP BY portion, except for aggregate fields. That is, you are selecting "office, name" but only grouping by "office". You need to group by "office, name" .

Answer (score 0):

The question you received is a bit unclear about how the data is to be presented considering that you can just inspect the rows visually to see who is in what office, or do aggregation in some language other than MySQL very simply.  Maybe he wants something like this?

```
SELECT
    office, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM
    my_db.employee
GROUP BY
    office
```

Comment: A big thanks to all the responses. Great board for getting help. I see now why GROUP BY was not doing what I thought it should do.